# Crash in Internet Explorer screen on startup

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I scanned registry files using CCleaner's Registry scan (about 3 months before), but the deleted registry files showed up in the result. After that when I open Internet Explorer, the attached image shows how it appears.

I'm pretty sure that this problem occurred after I deleted that registry file, which showed up in the scan. I still remember that it belonged to Internet Explorer.

I didn't made a backup before deleting that file.

My PC is a Win 7 64bit.

**What I've tried:**

I’ve reinstalled IE. I did SFC scan. Nothing worked. The screenshot is without any addon enabled. I relocated temp file… not worked. In Safe Mode, that 'breakout' never appear but I couldn't access to the web since I use USB modem...that application doesn't run in Safe mode

[image]
[Large image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYZng.png)

Comment: What all have you tried to resolve this issues ? Does it appear in No addons mode also ? Have you tried to reset it. Install the pending updates as i can see they are in screenshot. Does it happen in safe mode ?

Comment: I’ve reinstalled IE. I did SFC scan. Nothing worked. The screenshot is without any addon enabled. I  relocated temp file… not worked. In Safe Mode, that 'breakout' never appear but I couldn't access to the web since I use USB modem...that application doesn't run in Safe mode.

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like What do u mean by ' Install the pending updates as i can see they are in screenshot' ,  Do you meaning, just to install Windows updates?

Comment: I assume you have reset Internet Explorer?  If you have not you need to do that.

Comment: @Ramhound  I've reset IE several times now .didn't work.

Comment: And this issue only happens in IE? Did you try a System Restore?

Comment: @Dave Yes only IE. I didn't made system restore at that point---3 months before. I remember I deleted an IE registryfile. I am a newbie to tech so I didn't thought that this trouble is going to face me.

Comment: You could still use that restore point though...

Comment: @Dave I mean I didn't made a restore point 3 months ago.

Comment: @rayanA, not sure why you feel that matters... I've restored from many months back if the problem I face requires it

Comment: That is a rubbish image.. use a bigger image. And include the text of the error in your post, so that others with the error can find it. Think about it. Suppose somebody else had the problem and they never put the text of the error in your post, then when you look then you won't find their post will you. So don't do that to other people, it's selfish. Put the text of the error you get, in your post, so others can find your post. So that your question contributes more. Because anybody's solution is usually at least partly from another's contribution.

Comment: @barlop There is a `Large Image` text above, u click it. What my text is, _what the heck is this?_

Comment: @barlop  by the way I just started using internet enthusiastically about one year ago and my English is not very good. I am hoping to be better in future.

Comment: @rayanA Re your other question, I haven't got my knowledge via a course or training. Somebody suggested the CompTIA A+  I think you know a bit what you are doing when fixing a computer but maybe you'd benefit from feedback from somebody, while on the job.. I'm sure there are lots of people fixing computers that aren't very good but learn on the job.  Like they try to fix it they can't they ask their manager, he has a good idea.   You can be part of an IT Team and chat about your IT issues all day long with them and get good feedback and ideas.

Comment: @rayanA How old are you? Why have you only just started the internet enthusiastically? Many of us had it in the late 90s and were enthusiastic when we got it

Comment: @rayanA by the way, fixing computers, for most computer techs is a pain in the ass, and not really exciting . You research, you try to solve, you reinstall.you replace. it's that simple.

Comment: @barlop I am 29 yrs, I am currently jobless but I have few money on deposit. I belong to south Asia.

Comment: @barlop if u are from US u guys started using internet a long time ago but we are different. Our society isnt knowledgeable as u then.

Comment: @barlop I don't want make computer stuff as  my carrier . but in this age internet is vital for every one no matter what ur physical location is. so we have have basic knowledge to get around the dilemmas we face while playing around this stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26408/discussion-between-barlop-and-rayana).

Comment: @barlop u don't have to be a plumber as a carrier but if u have knowledge u can solve ur home dilemmas.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could try both the 32 and 64 bit versions of IE, and see if any of them work:

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe (32 bit)
- C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe (64 bit)

Comment: the I have opened IE in both version ,the same appearance is seen as above picture .

Comment: Ensure that your addons are disabled: Start>Control Panel>Internet Options, Advanced tab, uncheck "Enable third-party browser extensions"

Comment: And that you've reset the IE settings (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/reset-internet-explorer-settings) also.

Comment: You could start session with a different user (or create a new one), then start IE and see what happens.

Comment: I foun addons on Programms tab not in Adavanced tab

Comment: There are Microsoft add-ons like XML DOM document , HtmlDlgSafeHelperClass etc.. Should I Disable these also?

Comment: You can disable all of the addons safely. If it works, then enable one by one until you catch the faulty addon.